# Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm using Spring version 4.3.13.RELEASE, Spark Version 2.2.0-2.11, mongo-spark-connector_2.11(2.2.0), jackson 2.8.9. My application is working fine in Tomcat7 but getting the exceptions in Wildfly10

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType (Module "deployment.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot inherit from final class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138136/cannot-inherit-from-final-class-error)

Comment: There also might be clues [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40829949/1270789). Please also post a fuller stack trace.

Comment: I'm not using spring boot. I have posted the full stack trace.

Comment: This error is fixed with wildfly11.

Answer (score 8):

The spring boot 2.0 war created by the maven or gradle war plugin will work on jboss EAP 7.1. The same war file will through an exception on jboss EAP 7.0 server.

```
The exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType
```

The deployment exception arises becuse the jboss has it own jackson library and a class loading time verification error occours.

**SOLUTION :**
The solution to this problem is to add a jboss specific xml file named jboss-deployment-structure.xml in to the WEB-INF folder.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
<exclusions>
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
<module name="org.slf4j" />
</exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: In my opinion this answer should be the accepted one. 
It made me understand what is going wrong and explains how to solve it.

Comment: This is the solution if you are using JBoss EAP

Comment: This solution is not working with Wildfly server

Answer (score 0):

**I Have the same error while runnig the application in EAP 6.4 as below**
**I have migrated to EAP 7.1.0 and the error got resolved and application is runnig fine. This is because of the older version of jakson jars in jboss EAP6 please refer to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-5189 now its resolved in 7.x version**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter' defined in class path resourc
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org
springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Fac
ory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/Refer
nceType (Module "deployment.acsm.ear.CCP-API-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Cannot inherit from final class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
va:1254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:225)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:181)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:158)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationCo
text.java:250)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormCont
ntFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/data
ind/type/ReferenceType (Module "deployment.acsm.ear.CCP-API-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Cannot inherit from final class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType (Module "deployment.acsm.ear.CCP-API-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
main" from Service Module Loader): Cannot inherit from final class
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
```